# django send GET parameters to get_queryset into models.Manager

Tags: django, parameters, get, query-string, models

Hi all I'm trying to override get_queryset in my model manager in order to filter the data based on a querystring parameter called 'MYID'. The code I'm using is the following:

```
class MyFilterManager(models.Manager):


def get_queryset(self, request):

    test = request.GET.get('MYID')
    return super(MyFilterManager(, self).get_queryset(request).filter(level='Cars', MYID=test)
```

unfortunately it seems that the override is not working..I continue to get the same data even if I change the MYID... any ideas?

thanks

g

Comment: the `get_queryset` method in the `model manager` doesn't have a `request` paramater

Comment: I'm using test  variable with is a request.get one...it's the same in doing MYID= request.GET.get('MYID')..no?

Comment: One core problem with your approach here is you are combining the `view` with the `model`. These should be separate.  Also, no, `request` is not a param in `get_queryset`

Comment: Thank you Aaron. The fact is I have this model who is tied to the Admin (via modeladmin)  too, and I need to filter the results based on the request.GET params I get..that's why I'm not using a view and merging everything here... Do you have any idea on how I can solve the problem?

Comment: Check out this video and code snippets below on how to create custom querysets: https://godjango.com/51-better-models-through-custom-managers-and-querysets/  Then, once you have a custom method, call it from within your `views.py`

Comment: Hey I got the solution adding ''ids = request.GET.get('MYID', None) to the modeladmin and then passing the variable to the get_querysetmethod

Thank you for your time Aaron!